# How to force compiler not to consider any block of code if it comes from different button event

Tags: c#

In my case, I don't want this block:`if (Clicked == true){i = i+2;}` and `if (Clicked == false){i = i-2;}`to work if compiler comes inside of different particular button ;

> This is Button2 which returns elements of a sequence for a brand name given as
>   textBox4.

```
bool Clicked = false;
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var car = cars.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Brand == textBox4.Text);
            i = cars.FindIndex(c => c.Brand == textBox4.Text);
            if (car != null)
            {       
                label1.Text = car.Brand;
                label2.Text = car.Model;
                label3.Text = car.Color;
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This car is not in the list");
            }
        }
```

> And button3_click event should display next elements of the sequence.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var car = cars.Select(a => a);

        if (Clicked == true)
        {
            i=i+2;
        }
        if (i >= 0&&i < cars.Count)
        {

            label1.Text = car.ToArray()[i].Brand;
            label2.Text = car.ToArray()[i].Model;
            label3.Text = car.ToArray()[i].Color;
            i++;   //abc; i = 1;            
            Clicked = false;
        }

    }
```

> And Button4 displays the previous elements of a sequence

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Clicked == false)
        {
            i=i-2;
            Clicked = true;
        }
        var car = cars.Select(a => a);
        if (i >= 0&&i<=cars.Count)
        {

            label1.Text = car.ToArray()[i].Brand;
            label2.Text = car.ToArray()[i].Model;
            label3.Text = car.ToArray()[i].Color;
            i--;               
        }
    }
```

I don't want this :`if (Clicked == true){i = i+2;}` and this :`if (Clicked == false) {i=i-2;}` block of codes in the button3 and button4 (next and prev buttons) to run whenever I hit any one of them right after the codes inside of button2 have been worked. I couldn't work it out using bool flags as there're three cases needed to be considered. How to deal with it?

Comment: The code is unreadable.  Change TextBox4 to a ComboBox to get somewhere.

Comment: I don't think compiled means what you think it means and it's confusing me.

Comment: I think you might be misusing the word "compiled". Barring the `#if` directive, all of the code in your project will always be compiled. If you do use `#if`, those parts of the code might not be compiled depending on the compiler version or flags. But either way it's impossible for code not to be compiled based on what will happen at run time. The compiler can't look into the future and even if it could, it is perfectly possible that the condition you're describing might be true at some time and then not true at another time and you wouldn't want to have to recompile the code all the time.

Comment: Oh my god, a whole new there're... But why would you want buttons not-compiled?

Comment: @gilliduck  think of it as "run" or "work"

Comment: @CavidHummatov Then use "run".  "Compile" means something completely different and using that word as you are is confusing everyone.

Comment: Having a hard time understanding what you want.  Maybe move the functionality in the click events to there own methods which are called when a button is clicked.  Would make much easier to control program flow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try to answer this, not 100% sure exactly what you're asking...

My assumption is that you don't want the "if(Clicked..." part to run if you've just previously clicked button2, but after clicking either button3 or button4, it's fine to run the if statement.

Trying to figure out your code, I think you can shrink it way down to remove those.  First, the i++ should be removed from button2_Click

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i = cars.FindIndex(c => c.Brand == textBox4.Text);
    if(i >= 0)
    {
        var car = cars.ToArray()[i]; // no reason to search twice
        label1.Text = car.Brand;
        label2.Text = car.Model;
        label3.Text = car.Color;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This car is not in the list");
    }
}
```

Since the index "i" is not changed in button2_Click, it can be changed in the "next" and "previous" buttons before it's indexed.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // I don't think you need this
    // var car = cars.Select(a => a);
    if (i + 1 >= 0 && i + 1 < cars.Count)
    {
        i++;
        var car = cars.ToArray()[i];
        label1.Text = car.Brand;
        label2.Text = car.Model;
        label3.Text = car.Color;
    }
}

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (i - 1 >= 0 && i - 1 <= cars.Count)
    {
        i--;
        var car = cars.ToArray()[i];
        label1.Text = car.Brand;
        label2.Text = car.Model;
        label3.Text = car.Color;
    }
}
```

Since both button3_Click and button4_Click are almost identical, you could probably put them in a single event and check which button is pressed and increment/decrement as needed, but that's an opinion call, there are reasons not to do that as well.

I don't know what type "cars" is, but it may even be better to make a member variable to hold cars.ToArray() so ToArray doesn't have to be called so many times.